# Bisection Method : Estimating Iterations needed to approximate a root within three decimal places

Tags: calculus, analysis, numerical-methods, roots, bisection

I have been working on a problem involving the bisection method and the estimation of the number of iterations required to approximate the root of a given function to three decimal places. I have made some progress and wanted to seek your insights and expertise on my approach.

The problem statement is as follows: I am tasked with finding the total number of iterations needed to approximate the root of the equation $f(x) = x^4 - x^3 -2=0$ within three decimal places, in the interval $[1,2]$.

The error estimate is given by the relation : $\left| x_n - \hat{x}\right| \leq 0.5 \times 10^{-3}$ and it suffices to show that the upper bound of the error is : $\frac{2-1}{2^n}\leq 0.5 \times 10^{-3}$

So in order to estimate the number of iterations required I used the following formula:
$n \geq \frac{{\log(2 - 1) - \log(\epsilon)}}{{\log(2)}}$, where :

1. n is the number of iterations.
2. $\epsilon$ is the desired accuracy, in this case, $\epsilon = 0.5 \times 10^{-3}$ for three decimal places and rounding.

My calculations resulted in $n \geq 10.96578$, which I rounded up to $n=11$ indicating that at least 11 iterations are needed to approximate the root within three decimal places.

My question and concern: In the 11th iteration, the estimated root $x_{11} = 1.54345703$ rounds to $1.543$, whereas the real root is $\hat{x} = 1.54368901$ (which rounds to $1.544$). As you can see, we have not approximated the root in 3 decimal places as expected to do from the minimum number of iterations we found above. I am interested in discussing this small discrepancy between the estimated and real root. (If we do 12 iterations we obtain the correct approximation to $1.544$).

Is this level of discrepancy expected, even though we required the accuracy to be less than $0.5 \times 10^{-3}$? If so, why does it occur?

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: The relation between absolute error and number of correct decimals is a complicated one. In many cases the error bound $0.5\cdot 10^{-3}$ is a sufficient one. You can catch more cases where the decimals are correct after rounding when using $0.1\cdot 10^{-3}$. But even for that there will be corner cases where it is not correct. On the other hand, using superlinear methods one will often find that the last steps overshoots the accuracy goal significantly, so that such corner cases occur rarely.

Comment: Why do you round $\tilde x$ to count the number of coincident decimal places? The approximation $x_{11}$ is equal to $\tilde x$ up to the third decimal place.